# How to retrieve data from a DSN using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, dsn

I have a DSN (data source name) of the following format:

```
<driver>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>
```

and I am asked to retrieve rows from the corresponding database, which has a single table in this specific example and it is on AWS. I would like to do it using an endpoint in a Rails app.

I did some research online to look for an example about DSN, but couldn't find any help.

I am looking for some high level explanation of how to work with DSN, and ideally how to use Rails to communicate with the database

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is going to be useful for anybody, but this is as much info I could gather.

The DSN format is something like:

```
<driver>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>
```

Within rails it should be used like, assuming you want an array of users:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG.connect('<driver>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>')
puts conn.exec("SELECT count(*) FROM users").to_a
```